# Invoking the WiFi connections UI in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wifi

Prior to Windows 10, the WiFi connections UI could be invoked via a ShellExecute using the appropriate GUIDs/strings, details of which can be fairly easily found on the web. This changed in Windows 10. Although there is an API which can be used to programmatically manage WiFi connections (Native WiFi), and there is even a C# wrapper for it on CodePlex, I'd have to build my own UI around it; I can't find any information on how to launch the existing Windows 10 UI for managing WiFi connections. I'd rather not have to build my own duplicate of functionality which already exists just because the existing functionality can't be invoked programmatically.

Is it not publicly exposed? If it is callable, how is it done? Is it just a different ShellExecute?

Comment: Have there been any updates on this question? Facing a similar issue myself

Answer (score 1):

You could try running the command "%windir%\explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks:" . Alternatively, "Start ms-availablenetworks:" in command prompt.

I came across this on another post and seems like it should do what you're looking for. It hasn't worked for me but perhaps you'd have better luck.

There's plenty of other URIs available too. Here's the list I found: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78108-app-commands-list-windows-10-a.html

Comment: how to specify a network interface

Answer (score 1):

The Uri for the available networks is `ms-availablenetworks:`

So just use this in your code:

`var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-availablenetworks:"));`

Comment: Where does Windows.System come from? I can't find the assembly that would provide access to it...

Comment: Ahh... after further research, it's only for Windows Store apps...

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app

The listed URIs can be invoked via ShellExecute in a Win32 console app to successfully launch the appropriate dialogs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't satisfy my requirement because it depends on the explorer shell; my target environment replaces the explorer shell with a custom application, effectively removing the shell services needed for this to work.