# Triggering Network Flyout/Toast UI via command in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wifi, explorer, flyout

I'm looking for a way to trigger the WiFi menu shown on the taskbar (typically a black bar with available networks. NOT the Settings app). I've been looking for a command of sorts that could potentially be run through something like a batch file but have come up dry.

I have found lists of commands, like the one below, through which you could open the list of networks in the Settings app but unfortunately that's not what I'm after (I'd like to minimise the menu items an end user has access to):

https://www.neowin.net/news/psa-how-to-open-specific-settings-directly-in-windows-10-from-the-run-command

I also realise this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148711/invoking-the-wifi-connections-ui-in-windows-10) however the user never got any answers other than a similar list to the one above which they provided themselves. I'm hoping new answers and functionality would be available a year on.

In case Windows handles this differently, I am trying to have the above set up on Windows 10 on a tablet device (Linx 1010).

Any ideas of existing workarounds for this?

EDIT: I've come across suggestions to run "explorer ms-availablenetworks:" (as shown here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78108-app-commands-list-windows-10-a.html), however this doesn't seem to be working on my machine. Instead I simply get a Windows Store popup saying "You'll need a new app to open this: ms-availablenetworks"

Answer (score 0):

start ms-availablenetworks:

-or-

explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks:

Does work on normally operating good systems... If it doesn't for you something else is wrong or your not using regular windows 10 home/pro/ent

That is a very low end tablet with an Atom 64bit processor that comes with a 32bit OS.  I would reinstall Windows 10 64bit on that and everything should work fine afterwards..

Comment: I'm afraid updating the OS isn't an option.

I've tried those commands out on my Windows 10 Pro machine (not tablet) and all I get is a pop-up asking which app to open in. Similar commands are known to work well on Windows 8.1 and older, but apparently things have changed in Win 10